# improve io performance for very large input/ouput images in tensorflow-serving

Tags: tensorflow-serving

We have model in tensorflow which takes as input very large images (>40MPx) in uint16 format.  Model outputs same size image and runs on custom-compiled tf-serving with GPU. 
Largest issue seems to be related to image size as GPU inference takes ~1s while the whole HTTP request runs ~17s on local tf-serving with SSD drive.
Our model outputs tf.image.encode_png which is correctly named with suffix '_bytes' so that tf-serving does encode it properly as base64 [as per this blog post](https://medium.com/@zbnone/tensorflow-serving-accept-and-return-png-jpg-images-fab55649014c). Decoding from b64 takes 2.5s for this image.

This is fairly large overhead for what seem to be mainly IO operations due to json encoding.
Is there more efficient way how to reduce this overhead?

We do need GPU, large images, uin16 and tensorflow service. Client request can be assumed to be from same machine or local network at worst.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant to your situation, but I've found the REST API is much slower than the GRPC API, even for relatively small inputs - The expensive part is just encoding and decoding the JSON. You may want to look into the GRPC API if you're not already  - It is a bit harder to work with, though, you'll need some custom code client side.

Comment: @VeraFWC switching to GRPC improves latency about x2. And takes about 9s. I could still reduce this If I didn't do any PNG  encoding and looked into other pre/postprocessing ops but not too important for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using REST API but passing only input/output-filepath strings. This takes about 6s of which ~2s is just tf.io.encode_png. It might not be optimal solution from GPU utilization but this is acceptable now due to ease of use.

Using GRPC was almost as fast (~9s) and had more room for improvements.

REST API is really slow (~20s) but not deps on tensorflow hence good for client.

Tensorflow recently released [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/performance) and but this seems to require newest tf-serving.

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar problem, so far ended up with a model loaded with TF directly (tf.saved_model.load). Inference time is improved more than 2x. 
Run it on K8s cluster

Comment: Don't really want to write our own service and maintain it but rather piggy-back on what tensorflow offers already.